Problem with CUDA addresses
I've recently been working on a quick scene with fluid simulations to familiarize myself with them, but I keep running into multiple different errors regarding CUDA addresses being misaligned or not being able to be retained. I haven't yet found a solution that works, but I have tried some suggestions I read on other forum posts like putting my scene in a box, although I adjusted visibility because I'm using HDRI lightings, although I think I did it wrong. I saw someone talk about putting the scene in a box to prevent the light paths to just go to infinity. Although I haven't had this issue before, but I noticed since I had installed CUDA Toolkit it kind of broke Blender. I have removed it already but the issue persists. I am uploading my Blend file and the frames I was able to render. The file should be saved at frame 121, which is one of the frames that just won't render. If anyone could help me out that would be great as I've just very recently started using Blender and I would like to keep using and learning it. Thanks in advance.
My specs for more info:

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX550
VRAM: 2GB
Driver (as of 28.12.2024): Game Ready Driver 566.36, released 5.12.2024
CUDA version: 7.5, supports Toolkit 12.5 (which I had installed)
RTX: N/A, so I use CUDA for Cycles
CPU: Intel Core i5-1235U with integrated Graphics
iGPU: Intel Xe Graphics 80EU Mobile
RAM: 16GB
Blender Version: used both 4.2.3 LTS and 4.3.2, current save in 4.3+

Files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yxdsisp3H_0DZYjQ-CIeEVQNKy2f8Qpl?usp=sharing
If you need anymore information like the exact errors I am getting, please tell me and I will be sure to give you more in-depth information.

The scene renders fine(ignoring missing textures). You might be running out of VRAM. If not, report it as a bug.

Yeah, peak memory usage of the render for me is 1807 MB. So it's very likely your GPU is simply running out of VRAM. You obviously need some VRAM to do regular GPU stuff in addition to rendering, so the 1807 MB likely fills it completely and so it crashes.

So I followed the second comment and tried to reduce the tile size to 128 instead of 256 and it did still crash but I figured it was a good idea to try and render it from Command Prompt with blender -b fluid_test.blend -a and it's working now. I am rendering using 4.2.3 LTS though, I will check to see whether it also works with 4.3 later.
